# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of the space of 2x2 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I wanted to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the transformation of the space of $2\times 2$ matrices from $$T(A) = A^T$$ I initially thought representing the basis vectors in a $4 \times 4$ matrix like this would be helpful:

$$M = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$$
But then finding the characteristic polynomial this way is really long and tedious. Is there an easier way to do this without having to represent the transformation as a matrix by perhaps using some property of Transpose?

Comment: You're using the letter $A$ for too many things. I'm going to refer to your $4 \times 4$ matrix $M$ instead of $A$. Note that $M$ is orthogonal (specifically, a permutation matrix), hence its eigenvalues have absolute value $1$. So, possible candidates are $1$, $-1$, and complex conjugate pairs of the form $e^{i\theta}, e^{-i\theta}$. You know $1$ is an eigenvalue, for example with eigenvector $A = I$ (the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix). If $-1$ is an eigenvalue, there must be some nonzero $A$ that satisfies $A^T = -A$. Can you find such an $A$?

Comment: Finding the characteristic polynomial of $M$ is easy. Subtract $\lambda I$; find the determinant by expanding along the top row, then expanding along the bottom row, then evaluating the $2\times2$ determinant which remains. Couldn't be much easier!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to find the characteristic polynomial of $M$ (or indeed the matrix $M$ at all) in order to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $T$. You can work directly from the definition. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ with associated eigenvector $A$, then by definition
$$A^T = \lambda A$$
Taking transposes of both sides gives
$$A = \lambda A^T$$
Substituting the previous equation into this one, we obtain
$$A = \lambda^2 A$$
Assuming $A$ is nonzero, which is required for any eigenvector, we conclude that the only possible eigenvalues are $\lambda = 1$ and $\lambda = -1$.

Now consider the two cases.

(1) $\lambda = 1$

In this case, the first equation becomes $A^T = A$, so $A$ is an associated eigenvector if and only if it is nonzero and symmetric, i.e. of the form
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ b & c\end{pmatrix}$$

Note that there are three degrees of freedom (the values of $a$, $b$, and $c$), so this eigenspace has geometric multiplicity $3$.

(2) $\lambda = -1$

In this case, the first equation becomes $A^T = -A$, so $A$ is an associated eigenvector if and only if it is nonzero and antisymmetric, i.e. of the form
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & d \\ -d & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Note that there is one degree of freedom (the value of $d$), so this eigenspace has geometric multiplicity $1$.

Comment: You can shorten the first part by noting that $A= \lambda A^T$ so $A = \lambda^2 A$.

Comment: You can shorten further by noticing that if any diagonal element is non-zero, then $\lambda = 1$ and the matrix is symmetric. When all diagonal elements are zero, $\lambda$ cannot be zero or else $A = 0,$ then the matrix $A$ is either symmetric (already found) or antisymmetric.

Comment: @copper.hat Good observation, thanks! I have modified the argument accordingly.

Comment: @WillM. Thanks! In the modified version, I show that $\lambda = 1 \iff A$ is symmetric, and $\lambda = -1 \iff A$ is anti-symmetric. (For nonzero $A$, of course.)

Comment: How would I find the different eigenvectors, counting multiplicity, using this way?

Comment: @not_danish Isn't that exactly what I did when considering the two cases $\lambda = 1$ and $\lambda = -1$? If something is not clear, please let me know and I'll add details.

Comment: Yeah I got it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since , each row sum of $M$ is $1$, $1$ is an eigenvalue of $M$.

You can also see by taking vector $v=(1,1,1,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ such that $Mv=1v$

Then , by definition of eigenvalue of a linear operator, $1$ is eigenvalue of $M$.

Now , we see that dimension of the kernel of $(M-1I_{4 \times 4})$ is $3$.

That mean , geometric multiplicity of eigenvalue $1$ is $3$.

Now ,as $M$ is real symmetric, so, M is diagnolisable.

Hence , algebraic multiplicity of eigenvalue $1 = $geometric multiplicity of $1$ $=3$

Now , $trace(M)=2$

So, if we take unknown eigenvalue as $\lambda$

then, $1+1+1+\lambda=2 \implies \lambda =-1 $

So, all eigenvalues are $1,1,1,-1$